# Multiple drop down box values send to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

[image]

I have to create an above kind of dynamic UI with drop down boxes.The values of drop down boxes are fixed as shown above.

My question is I need to send payment type drop down box values to mvc controller.I need to send value of selected drop down against the service key.I don't have any idea how to do that.
Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Payment types can be like enum. It's look like below.

```
public enum PaymentOption
    {
        [Display(Name = "Select Payment Type")]
        None = 1,

        [Display(Name = "Service Hourly")]
        ServiceHourly = 2,

        [Display(Name = "Salary Flat Rate")]
        SalaryFlatRate = 3,

        [Display(Name = "% of Appointment")]
        PercentOfAppointment = 4,

        [Display(Name = "Per Appointment")]
        PerAppointment = 5,

    }
```

Comment: could you show a little piece of code (view, actions involved...), please ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Actually I don't have any idea how to send above kind of multiple drop downs to controller. So I didn't do any implementation yet.Any idea (sample code) highly appreciate.

Comment: i think in this scenario you can use Jquery ajax method

Comment: @AbiRuban could you explain bit more ?

Comment: are you familiar with POST parameters /JSON? this might be of big help in creating an answer, as these two are the main transfer methods of data. btw. i had some similar problems and i found it impossible to rely on MVC only. you will need at least jQuery for a clean submit

Comment: @Sampath You must at least have classes ? You have a class Service, a class Payment ? Could you show them ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I am going to save these values in a new junction table.Due to M:M relationship.So I can handle server side part (still not stared).Before that I need to know how to send multiple combo box values into controller. Any pseudo code like thing is sufficient for me.Just to get the idea how to send from view.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus payment type doesn't have any class.It's just a enumerator kind of values(Hard code combo as shown above.It's fixed).

Comment: @Vogel612 could you explain your solution bit ?

Comment: @Sampath the link I put shows how to get selected value from dropdowns and also how to dinamically create them on view by using for. Have you looked at it?

Comment: @Gmoliv yes I did.But it's for simple text box.Not for drop downs.

Comment: @Sampath i was in the necessity to use ext.net either way as a pre-fixed requirement and was able to handle the multiple checkboxes in code behind. i do not recommend that though, if you don't have ext.net either way

Comment: @Vogel612 I have completed above task by using jquery drop down.I will put that answer later.Thanks for support.

Comment: @Sampath have you really read it? It's exactly the same logic for ANY kind of input you want to bind, from hidden to textbox, combobox, radiobox etc, you just need to adapt the code!

Comment: @Gmoliv Actually I have completed above task by using Jquery drop down box.So I will put my answer later. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

try this example code code

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Youractionname")';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '{ddl1: "' + ddl1value+ '",ddl2: "' + ddl2value+ '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Youractionname(int ddl1, int ddl2)
    {
        //do work
    }
```

Comment: My problem is drop downs are dynamic.So cannot send like you showed.Any idea?

Comment: are you generated the id for that drop downs ?

Comment: Actually drop down values are fixed.may be hard code or enumerate values.No need to have any Ids for that.

Comment: i think you will set the "id" property then try my above code it may be help us. otherwise u wil post ur code and i wil try......

Comment: Still I am trying to find a solution.I did not do any code yet.Problem with your solution is it's a dynamic drop downs.So initially cannot predict the count of drop downs.Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list for "services" and bind list items to your model.

```
public class Service {
  string Name { get;set;}
  int PaymentType { get;set;}
  float HourlyRate { get;set;}
}

public class MyModel { 
  ICollection<Service> services { get;set;}
  [...]
}
```

Then, follow this article to create your view and bind your services list correctly:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx